# Cannot pass complex object to another Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass an object using TempData to another action method. Instead of redirecting to the action method, the controller gives me a white screen with the current action method in the URL. If I comment out the line where I pass the object to TempData, it redirects correctly. Is my object too complex to pass? Is there an alternative way of passing a complex object to another action methods?

Where I pass the object to TempData:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");
    else
    {                
        var path = Path.Combine(
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                "processes.json");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

        }
        RetrieveModels rm = rm = new RetrieveModels(path);
        List<FoundPattern> foundList = new List<FoundPattern>();               
        List<ProcessModel> processes = rm.Processes;
        FindPatterns findp = new FindPatterns(processes, pt.KpiPatterns);
        foundList = findp.fp;
        TempData["list"] = foundList.ToList();
        TempData["Name"] = "Multiple Business Processes";
        return RedirectToAction("Overview");
    }           
}
```

Action method I want to get redirected to:

```
public IActionResult Overview()
{
    var list = TempData["list"] as List<FoundPattern>;
    ViewData["Name"] = TempData["Name"];
    return View(list);
}
```

List of objects I'm trying to pass to TempData:

```
public class FoundPattern
{
    public KpiPattern pattern = new KpiPattern();
    public List<FoundElement> elements = new List<FoundElement>();
}
```

List of objects within object:

```
public class FoundElement
{
    public List<string> ElementNames = new List<string>();
    public bool Present { get; set; }
}
```

Response headers when it works:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /Home/Overview
Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=CfDJ8Mu_qDgU_59HncGqqkEm39LG_cUi_rzUyuXXaEYreUFPL2etHRuHPv_5GVKDLcIIcvFhQg1KOzDBfhbvDbjZDpcp8JYzq5kpLHtfnw962pyXNHyCNbx_MOkKwGFSG_dQ_M7LlSVxWYHjqalsSe26K4IlRfGN8V9B5MAgIhWoURgF; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcWkFUXHNvdXJjZVxyZXBvc1xLUEl0b29sXEtQSXRvb2xcSG9tZVxVcGxvYWRGaWxl?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 10:38:40 GMT
Content-Length: 0`

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesite=strict
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcWkFUXHNvdXJjZVxyZXBvc1xLUEl0b29sXEtQSXRvb2xcSG9tZVxPdmVydmlldw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 10:38:40 GMT`

Response headers when it doesn't work:

`HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcWkFUXHNvdXJjZVxyZXBvc1xLUEl0b29sXEtQSXRvb2xcSG9tZVxVcGxvYWRGaWxl?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 10:41:28 GMT
Content-Length: 0`

Comment: Does `TempData["Name"]` work? TempData is really just session data, so do sessions work in general? If you are worried about the object being to complex serialize it to JSON, store the JSON in TempData and deserialize when you need it.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Thank you for your response. `TempData["Name"]` works. I also used TempData to store a simple string list and it worked fine. But now that it is more complex, it doesn't work anymore. I suppose serializing it to JSON is the only solution...

Comment: @CalC TempData should be configured, because `TempData["Name"]` works fine. Just to check, I did add the code to configure the TempData provider, but it didn't help.

Comment: @mjwills Yes. I even get the following line in the locals window right before exiting the action method: https://imgur.com/a/nE0WJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `CookieTempDataProvider` to manage `TempData`. Alas, it results in storing the `TempData` in [cookies](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/CookieTempDataProvider.cs), as the name suggests.

The problem is that your data is [too large](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/) to fit in the cookie. You may wish to use a [different](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/225) `ITempDataProvider` implementation (such as `SessionStateTempDataProvider`).

Comment: I just switched to `SessionStateTempDataProvider`. Thanks for the solution. Do you know what the max size is in this type of implementation? I cannot find it anywhere.