# RedirectToAction is getting ignored in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a crud app in asp.net core , From Add ActionResult after adding record when I use RedirectToAction then it does not redirect to that action.

*It does redirect when request is GET, but in case of POST it does not.*

Below is my code:

```
public IActionResult Add(AuditSchedules model)
    {
        try
        {
            int ScheduleID;
            int TotalDays;
            DateTime start;
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            TempData["state"] = util.Get_State();
            TempData["branch"] = li;
            TempData["Catg"] = ctx.CategoryMaster.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CategoryName, Value = x.CategoryId.ToString() }).ToList();
            int count = 0;
            if (HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                using (var ctx = new QuestionnaireEntities())
                {
                    count = ctx.AuditSchedules.Where(x => (x.State == model.State) &&
                                                            (x.Branch == model.Branch) &&
                                                             (x.StaffId == model.StaffId) &&
                                                              (x.FromDate == model.FromDate)).Count();
                }
                if (count <= 0)
                {
                    TotalDays = (int)(model.ToDate.Subtract(model.FromDate)).TotalDays + 1;
                    start = model.FromDate;
                    model.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
                    model.Icon = util.GetIcon(model.CategoryId);
                    model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    model.IsCompleted = "N";
                    using (var ctx = new QuestionnaireEntities())
                    {
                        ctx.AuditSchedules.Add(model);
                        //ctx.SaveChanges();
                        ScheduleID = model.ScheduleId;
                        for (int i = 0; i < TotalDays; i++)
                        {
                            AuditSubSchedule subModel = new AuditSubSchedule();
                            subModel.ScheduleId = ScheduleID;
                            subModel.ScheduleDate = start;
                            ctx.AuditSubSchedule.Add(subModel);
                            //ctx.SaveChanges();
                            start.AddDays(1);
                        }
                    }
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Schedule For " + model.StaffName + " Created Successfully";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedules");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Schedule AllReady Exist , Try a Different Combination <br> [ Hint : Different State , Branch , StaffID , Fromdate]";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedules");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
      return View(model);
    }
```

After Adding the record I am using return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedules");
 but it does nothing. when request is Get type than it works well , but when I post model into it than it does not redirect.

As a matter of fact it works well in MVC5 (does not matter its a GET request or POST)
How can I redirect in ASP.Net Core ?

**Update One**
Before Post Network Tab response 
[image]

After Post Network Tab Response

[image]

**Update two**

[image]

[image]

In Network Logs Location of Add is showing not found ,

Comment: It works fine. Are you using ajax to post the data?

Comment: No , I am  using submit button inside form , Purpose is to return to main page with list of all records after adding new record

Comment: Tick "Preserve" log and re-run so we can see the actual POST request itself (and hopefully the subsequent GET when the browser follows the redirect header). The only thing which is important in that log is the only thing which is missing. It gets destroyed when you post back because it clears the log for the new page, but if you use Preserve Log it'll stay there.

Comment: @Jack Are you sure, that your code works fine? Because if some exception occurs in a try..catch block, the **return View(model)** is called and you will stay on the same page

Comment: @LukasKubis , yes . There is no exception and code works . It saves the Data into Database

Comment: I guess the problem is that the **model** is null and it crashes when calling **return View(model)**. This is the reason why are you getting Internal Server Error (500)

Comment: @LukasKubis , it does not hit return View(model).  after posting data , There is Return redirect to action statement and debugger control does return from that statement but never go into index

Comment: try to comment everything and just add this line. **if (HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST") { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedules"); }** to make sure that redirection works fine :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot pass complex object to another Action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661052/cannot-pass-complex-object-to-another-action-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `TempData`, combined with the fact that ASP.NET Core [defaults](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/225) to using the [`CookieTempDataProvider`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/CookieTempDataProvider.cs) is the cause of your issues.

Basically, you are trying to serialise large objects into cookies. The resulting cookie is [too large](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/) - resulting in a 500  (which is very hard to diagnose, as you have experienced - since the `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schedules");` call does *appear* to execute fine).

As such, the `RedirectToAction` is a red herring - it is unrelated. The multiple assignment to `TempData` is the real cause - likely mainly this one:

```
TempData["Catg"] = ctx.CategoryMaster.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CategoryName, Value = x.CategoryId.ToString() }).ToList();
```

You may wish to use a different `ITempDataProvider` implementation (such as `SessionStateTempDataProvider`). *Or avoid `TempData` altogether.*

*This issue won't happen with MVC5 since it doesn't use `CookieTempDataProvider`.*

Comment: Don't flag it as a dupe and then repeat your own answer again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @StephenMuecke . My objective here was to provide an answer specific for the OP's question (i.e. not just a repeat), while also pointing out the similarity to my answer elsewhere (i.e. fully transparent). Feel free to flag this answer for deletion if you feel strongly.

Comment: It does not need to be deleted (in fact I up-voted it). But you had already flagged it as a duplicate, therefore you should not have added an answer

Comment: I understand your viewpoint @StephenMuecke. Thanks for raising it.

Comment: @mjwills , Thanks for the solution . Its redirecting After removing TempData from my code . Can you refer any example of any post where I can use Both mechanism together in ASP.Net Core . I mean TempData is not used here just to hold SelectList , Its also used to show message on successful execution of code . AfterRedirecting I want to Show Some Text on Index page says , "Added Successfully" Or "Update Successful" . What should  I use here to Achieve this . Note : Not Looking for Client Side Approach , Just By C#

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#configuring-session may be worth a read @Jack .

Comment: I think I have a similar problem, cookies are limited to 4096 bytes in Chrome.  So I think switching to the SessionStateTempDataProvider would help as I am serializing some objects that get passed to another action for deserialization, but in my case it was just crashing.  The entire thing I had to restart the debugging session each time as it would give an Error 500 across the board - .NET Core 3.1.