# TempData fails in a web farm

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When deployed to a web farm (basically 2 Windows Server 2016 boxes), the code below fails to read data from TempData.  The sequence of events is as follows: UserInfo page is POSTed to, TempData is set, then redirects to the GET of UserInfo.  In the GET TempData can't be read.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserInfo(Model model) {
    TempData["Model"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return RedirectToAction("UserInfo");            
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserInfo() {
    string serialized = (string)TempData["Model"];
    if (serialized != null) {
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(serialized);
        return View(model);
    } else {
        // nothing here redirect home
        return RedirectToAction("Landing");
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the std log (but doesn't cause an exception in my code):

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider[3]
      The temp data cookie .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider could not be loaded.

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {0dd9c024-af79-407b-9820-db7f094975f9} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider.LoadTempData(HttpContext context)
```

P.S. I should mention that this code works in non-web farm IIS instances and on Asure shared hosting.

Comment: Would it be an option to not use `TempData`?

Comment: @mjwills I removed it for now, but I am losing the Post/Redirect/Get pattern and users wouldn't be able to click the Back button.

Comment: PRG doesn't _require_ `TempData` (you could instead store the data in a temporary cache and then pass the key to the cache in the querystring is one example). I've literally never used `TempData` in 10 years of ASP.NET work and PRG (I avoid it, just like I avoid session state). But let's put that to one side.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-2.2#required-configuration have you done this? How are you doing key storage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @mjwills There is no common cache between the boxes.  Therefore TempData seems like it would be perfect since it stores things in cookies.

Comment: @mjwills I didn't do any of the stuff in the links...mostly because this is the first time I've heard of it.  Thanks.  I'll check it out.

Comment: `There is no common cache between the boxes.` I am surprised there isn't _some_ form of common data storage between servers (e.g SQL Server). But OK, I'll take your word for it. Another option you could consider is passing the data itself in the querystring. `Therefore TempData seems like it would be perfect since it stores things in cookies.` Also keep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661052/cannot-pass-complex-object-to-another-action-method in mind.

Comment: `I didn't do any of the stuff in the links...` That is likely your issue then. Your servers are likely encrypting / decrypting cookies with different keys.

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells you everything you need to know. It attempted to read the cookie, but decryption failed, specifically because the key could not be found in the data protection key ring. That means you're not sharing data protection between each instance in the farm. Even though it's the same app, each instance is effectively it's own entity. As such, you need to treat it like any other scenario where data protection needs to be shared between sites: namely by using a common key ring store and ensuring that the same application name is used:

```
services.AddDatProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("Shared Name")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
```

With that, each instance will be able to read the cookies set by other instances, which then will make `TempData` work between instances.

Comment: I did just [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429757/how-does-one-distribute-data-protection-keys-with-a-net-core-web-app?noredirect=1).  Still, I wish there was a way to turn off encryption as I don't need it for this instance of TempData usage.

Comment: This is not a function of `TempData`, but of cookies in general in ASP.NET Core. They're encrypted by default. That's very much a feature you want, even if it doesn't matter in this one particular case.

Comment: Afaik, only Session cookies get encrypted.  Regular cookies that are sent aren't.

Comment: Any cookie ASP.NET Core sets itself. If you create a custom cookie, no/